# How to set Unlimited SQL rawQuery?

Tags: android, sqlite

I use this code to limit the number of history item in my dictionary app. The `historyNum` is defaulted to 50 items.

```
SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MyApp.getAppContext());
        String historyNum = SP.getString("history","50");

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + HISTORY_NAME +
                " WHERE " + STATUS + " ORDER BY " + STATUS + " DESC LIMIT " + historyNum ;
```

I would like to add a new option, unlimited item but I don't know what number should in put in `historyNum`.

I understand I can simply remove the limit by using:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + HISTORY_NAME +
                " WHERE " + STATUS + " ORDER BY " + STATUS + " DESC " ;
```

However, the `historyNum` is set under `PreferenceManager` whereby user can select how many history item they want to save. Changing my code to above will make my `PreferenceManager` not working.

Comment: I am guessing you mean remove the limit rather than `unlimited`. If that so then just remove that `LIMIT` part.

Comment: Please check my edited question. I can't simply remove the `LIMIT` because of `PreferenceManager`.

Comment: Use the negative numbers instead like `-1` if it is negative then it is unlimited but if it is a positive number then it has a specific limit although you will use `getInt()` instead.

Comment: Thank you. Consider put it as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the negative numbers instead like `-1` if it is negative then it is unlimited but if it is a positive number then it has a specific limit although you will use `getInt()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Store a new value in PreferenceManager, something like a boolean value with "unlimitedHistory".

Then in your code

```
boolean useUnlimitedHistory = SP.getString("unlimitedHistory", false);
String sql = "";
if (useUnlimitedHistory) {
    sql =  "SELECT * FROM " + HISTORY_NAME +
                " WHERE " + STATUS + " ORDER BY " + STATUS + " DESC " ;
} else {
    sql = "SELECT * FROM " + HISTORY_NAME +
                " WHERE " + STATUS + " ORDER BY " + STATUS + " DESC LIMIT " + historyNum ;
}
```